# Where can I find the URL for a Facebook (App on Facebook) Canvas Page App?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

After creating an "App on Facebook", how can I find the URL to actually view it within the Facebook chrome?

In the image below (from [Facebook's Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/)), the top line shows the url for the Canvas Page withing facebook. However, my "edit app" page does NOT have this field, but is otherwise identical.

[image]

The URL doesn't appear to be listed anywhere in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/, and I just don't know where else to look.

Ideas?

Comment: Now, I can't find a way to create a canvas app on facebook. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out after reading the documentation more carefully ;-)

To get the URL to appear, you need to set the App "Namespace" in the settings.